# How to document C++ non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

Are there any guidelines on how C++ non-type template parameters should be documented with Doxygen?

For example, how should we comment the non-type template parameter `Size` in the `Test` class?

```cpp
template<int Size>
class Test { };
```

I tried such declaration:

```cpp
/// \tparam Size
```

But it gives the following warning:

> "'\tparam' command used in a comment that is not attached to a template declaration [-Wdocumentation]".

Comment: As far as we can see, the warning is correct since the comment doesn't seem to be attached to the template. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that we can copy and replicate your problem.

Comment: Besides the MWE which version of doxygen are you using and also include in the MWE the setting in your doxygen configuration file that are different fro the default configuratio file. The warning message also doesn't look like to come from doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaDoc-style comments in my code. I tested with this:

```
/**
 * This is my test.
 *
 * @param Size Interesting
 */
template <int Size>
class Test {
};
```

And it produced this:

```
Detailed Description

template<int Size>
class Test< Size >

This is my test.

Parameters
Size    Interesting
```

Comment: Why do you use `@param` and not `@tparam`. Which doxygen version did you use?

Comment: @albert Ah, I've never used tparam. My doxygen is 1.8.14.

Comment: I tried it with tparam and got only slight differences. It says template parameters instead of parameters. I don't use the /// style of commenting, so it may be something strange about how it handles that.

Comment: I think there is nothing strange, `Size` is a template parameter isn't it?